# Unable to upload a file to a python FTP server running locally on Windows 10

Tags: python, docker, windows-10, ftp-server, pyftpdlib

I'm running a FTP server with the below python code in a docker container on windows 10.

```
import os

from pyftpdlib.authorizers import DummyAuthorizer
from pyftpdlib.handlers import FTPHandler
from pyftpdlib.servers import FTPServer

FTP_PORT = 8080
FTP_USER = "test"
FTP_PASSWORD = "test"

FTP_DIRECTORY = "/root/srv/ftp"


def main():
    authorizer = DummyAuthorizer()

    authorizer.add_user(FTP_USER, FTP_PASSWORD, FTP_DIRECTORY, perm='elradfmw')

    handler = FTPHandler
    handler.authorizer = authorizer
    handler.banner = "pyftpdlib based ftpd ready."
    #handler.passive_ports = range(60000, 65535)

    address = ('', FTP_PORT)
    server = FTPServer(address, handler)

    server.max_cons = 256
    server.max_cons_per_ip = 5

    server.serve_forever()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When I tried to upload a file to this FTP server it is failing with below statement.

`curl -T test.txt ftp://localhost:8080/ --user test:test`

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:04 --:--:--     0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8080 after 4040 ms: Couldn't connect to server
```

Below are the docker logs.

```
2023-08-04 12:46:37 [I 2023-08-04 07:06:37] 172.11.52.1:56758-[] FTP session opened (connect)
2023-08-04 12:46:37 [I 2023-08-04 07:06:37] 172.11.52.1:56758-[test] USER 'test' logged in.
2023-08-04 12:46:41 [I 2023-08-04 07:06:41] 172.11.52.1:56758-[test] FTP session closed (disconnect).
```

Please help me fix this.